# protobuf-net UseImplicitZeroDefaults and Enum defaults

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We're trying to use protobuf-net but having trouble understanding UseImplicitZeroDefaults which we now disable in a custom RuntimeTypeModel. We initially used the default RuntimeTypeModel but noticed boolean properties were not being cloned even though a DefaultValue was being specified, i.e. DefaultValue=true but when set to false the cloned property would always be true.

We resolved this by creating a custom RuntimeTypeModel which has allowed us to set UseImplicitZeroDefaults to false. But setting this to false is causing the following error;

```
ProtoBuf.ProtoException: No wire-value is mapped to the enum
```

Note that some of our enums are non-zero based, could this be causing an issue? How can we clone/serialize boolean properties and enums (mixture of non-zero and zero based)?

Edit: I used some of the information found at: [protobuf-net enum serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135569/protobuf-net-enum-serialization?rq=1) and can report:

```
[ProtoMember(10), DefaultValue(SiteType.Partition)]
public SiteType Type { get; set; }
```

Still results in the "No wire-value" error.

```
[ProtoMember(10, IsRequired = true)]
public SiteType Type { get; set; }
```

Still results in the "No wire-value" error.

```
public enum SiteType
{
    Error = 0,
    ...
```

This works but ideally we would like to leave our enum clean.
Perhaps a cleaner way to specify the default value:

```
[DefaultValue(SiteType.Server)]
public enum SiteType
{
    Server = 1,
    Monkey = 2
    ...
```

Comment: I'll have to take a look - too late for tht tonight; but: does it work if you set IsRequired=true?

Comment: IsRequired is set at the property level however to avoid over decoration of our classes we use [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]. So we're not setting anything at the property level, perhaps we should!

Comment: I will investigate, to see if something is wrong here

Comment: Marc, I updated my question to reflect the results from a few tests. Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Marc, just to add I was able to resolve this issue but setting a default enum value in the constructor of the class object to be serialized. This resolved the issue and avoids us having to use a protobuf-net attribute on the enum property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved this issue by specifying a default enum for any non-zero based enums. We specified the default in the constructor of the class being serialized. This was by far the tidiest solution and didn't require any additional protobuf-net attributes.

Plus, it made sense to explicitly set a default value for non-zero based enum properties.

Comment: thanks for the update; I will still investigate, but: things get hectic around xmas etc